# Creating NSPredicate from string

Tags: iphone, string, nspredicate

I need to form a predicate from multiple arrays of values. So I thought I can initially form a string with all the values, and then pass that string for usage in a predicate, i.e

```
NSString* stringForPredicate  = [[NSString alloc] init];
if (fromDate != nil) {
          stringForPredicate = [stringForPredicate stringByAppendingFormat:@"(Date > %@ AND Date < %@)", fromDate, toDate];
    }
```

There are further calculations that I do to form the final predicate string.

Now, I want the predicate to use this string. I thought that something like this would work:

```
   NSPredicate* filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@",stringForPredicate];
```

But it doesnt and throws the exception:

'Unable to parse the format string "%@"'

Is there a way I can make this work?

thanks,

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The *stringForPredicate* variable actually contains the **format_string**. So, you need to assign that variable in place of the format_string, and pass the **args** after that, seperated by commas, like this.

```
NSSring *stringForPredicate = @"(Date > %@ AND Date < %@)";
NSPredicate* filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:stringForPredicate, fromDate, toDate];
```

---

For compound predicates:

```
NSMutableArray *subPredicates = [NSMutableArray array];

if (fromDate != nil) {

    NSPredicate *from_predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Date > %@", fromDate];
    [subPredicates addObject:from_predicate];
}

if (toDate != nil) {

    NSPredicate *to_predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Date < %@", toDate];
    [subPredicates addObject:to_predicate];
}

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:subPredicates];
```

Comment: hmm, I understand it, but the above statement is just one of the variable substitution that I am doing. In fact I am looping over an array, and depending on certain conditions, I am appending the predicate string with values. So, I need a way by which either I can use the string, or keeping on appending conditions to an existing predicate, in which case I can use the predicate inside the loop directly, instead of using the string. Any ideas? thanks.

Comment: @user542584: Yes. You can use *NSCompoundPredicate*.

Comment: Hi, yes, I tried the compound predicates on the dates and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Wont this do it?

```
  NSPredicate* filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:stringForPredicate];
```

or you have to do this

```
NSPredicate* filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",stringForPredicate]];
```

From the [reference documents](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001793-SW4)

> **Format String Summary**
>
> It is important to distinguish between
>   the different types of value in a
>   format string. Note also that single
>   or double quoting variables (or
>   substitution variable strings) will
>   cause %@, %K, or $variable to be
>   interpreted as a literal in the format
>   string and so will prevent any
>   substitution.

Try this

```
stringForPredicate = [stringForPredicate stringByAppendingFormat:@"(Date > %@) AND (Date < %@)", fromDate, toDate];
```

Comment: did u notice this in my updated answer **Note also that single or double quoting variables (or substitution variable strings) will cause %@, %K, or $variable to be interpreted as a literal in the format string and so will prevent any substitution.**

Comment: Hi, yes, I tried many possible combinations, with and without quotes, using $ etc. It just does not like that my data is already contained in the format string. Upon further reading, I suppose I have to use compound predicates - and form individual predicate objects rather than string objects - then compound them together. Pls let me know if u have any other idea.

Comment: Hi , your updated answer is just going to change the way my string variable is going to be constructed - already I am using the same syntax: stringbyAppendingFormat to construct the string by looping inside an array. The error is actually when the predicate object is being formed with string already containing data. That is causing the error..so unfortunately this does not work either. I tried compound predicate on the date variable, and it works, Now I have to put it inside the array and its a lot of code! appreciate your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For those using swift:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate.init("Date > %@ AND Date < %@", fromDate, toDate);
```